# Apktool showing exception during reassembly

Tags: java, android, smali

I Disassembled my APK using `apktool`. I encrypted all of the constant strings in smali files. After that, I tried to reassemble the app using `apktool`, but it is showing an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: Could not smali file: java.io.FileInputStream@349471
at brut.androlib.src.DexFileBuilder.addSmaliFile(DexFileBuilder.java:45)
at brut.androlib.src.DexFileBuilder.addSmaliFile(DexFileBuilder.java:33)
at brut.androlib.src.SmaliBuilder.buildFile(SmaliBuilder.java:64)
at brut.androlib.src.SmaliBuilder.build(SmaliBuilder.java:48)
at brut.androlib.src.SmaliBuilder.build(SmaliBuilder.java:35)
at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildSourcesSmali(Androlib.java:222)
at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildSources(Androlib.java:179)
at brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:170)
at brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:154)
at brut.apktool.Main.cmdBuild(Main.java:182)
at brut.apktool.Main.main(Main.java:67)
```

Comment: Have you tried to recompile without making any changes?

Comment: yes without changes it is not showing any exception.

Comment: how did you encrypt the strings in Smali files, can you show one of such change you did?

Comment: Apktool swallows errors from Smali. Try using Smali directly.

Comment: I had the same problem when changing the package name. Then I followed this [guide](https://community.thunkable.com/t/a-complete-guide-to-changing-app-package-name-custom-keystore-signing/17021). The step where the path corresponding to the new package name was created in the smali folder fixed it.